# not able to use int with SQLite put method, compiler error, Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting compiler error in eclipse for the put method of SQLite class, the "put" is underlined and I get the message, "change type of "KEY_CHECKBOX_STATUS" to String"

```
   contentValues.put(KEY_CHECKBOX_STATUS, checkBoxStatus);
```

how can I fix this problem so I can use integer?  Or is it impossible to use int for the put method?    Do I have to use string for everything and cast it back from string to int when I need to?

database variables:

```
    public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "my_database";
    public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "my_table";
    public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final int KEY_CHECKBOX_STATUS = 0;
    public static final String KEY_CHECKBOX_LABEL = "Example Label";

  //create table MY_DATABASE (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
    private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
     "CREATE_TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " (" + "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +  
     + KEY_CHECKBOX_STATUS + " BIT, " + KEY_CHECKBOX_LABEL + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

insert method:

```
 public void insert(Integer checkBoxStatus){

          ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
          contentValues.put(KEY_CHECKBOX_STATUS, checkBoxStatus); // <-- compiler error
          sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
         }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first param in `put` method has to be a string, `checkBoxStatus` can be integer. Just change

```
public static final int KEY_CHECKBOX_STATUS = 0;
```

to

```
public static final String KEY_CHECKBOX_STATUS = "check_box_status;
```

Answer (score 0):

Key require a String object. int is a primitive type, so it will not have methods such as toString(). Use Integer instead of int, and call the toString method.